# Trouble converting std::string to char array

Tags: c++, string, char, protocol-buffers

I am having trouble converting std::string to char array in c++. For context: I want to send data over MPI using protobuf. Fist I use protobuf to serialize a float with serializeToString() which returns a std::string. I convert this to char array to be able to send it over MPI. Then I dezerialize with parseFromString() (I am aware that protobuf might not be the fastest alternative). The problem is that this sometimes fails and sometimes not. It depends on the float number i try to send. For example the number 1.03 is serialized, sent and received without problem while if I send 2.03 the received message is 0.

Now I have traced this to the step where i convert the serialized std::string to the char arrray. Printing the std::string after serializeing the float 2.01 gives "ף@". Printing this after converting this to char array (using the function .c_str()) gives the ouput "ף". For some reason the "@" disapers and I can't figure out why.

If I create the string "ף@" by myself the conversion works just fine. So the following code

```
protobuf.set_float(2.01);
std::string serialized_message;
protobuf.SerializeToString(&serialized_message);
std::cout << "std::string: " << serialized_message << std::endl;
std::cout << "char: " << serialized_message.c_str() << std::endl;
```

gives the output:
std::string: "ף@"
char: "ף"

while the following code

```
std::string a = "ף@";
std::cout << "std::string: " << a << std::endl;
std::cout << "char: " << a.c_str() << std::endl;
```

gives the output:
std::string: "ף@"
char: "ף@"

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: I assume the string is binary so there’s a null so printing the char pointer stops at it. Check the actual contents based on the length of the string.

Comment: From the documentation: "Note that the bytes are binary, not text; we only use the string class as a convenient container."

Comment: Saying the same differently: those strings are not to be printed. Printing them out will output garbage that is not guaranteed to (a) be meaningful (b) be useful (c) be deserializable (d) look the same after printing out on various machines

Comment: To print the initial value, you should deserialize your double first. If you serialized with SerializeToString, then when you want to read the message you should deserialize with ParseFromString, then read your float as float (not as string)